# java download a file sourced from a database to PC

Tags: java, download

I am getting an image (jpeg or pdf) from a database and want to download it to the PC. However, the image is not recognised at `!file.exists()`. This points to `File file = new File(resourceDetail.getResourseImage());` being incorrect. What is the correct way to code this please?

Note: `resourceDetail.getResourseImage()` is the actual image not a path.

My code is:

```
        resourceDetail = MySQLConnection.resourceDownload(fileID);

        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(resourceDetail.getResourseImage());
            System.out.println("resourceDetail.getResourseImage(): " + resourceDetail.getResourseImage());

            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File does not exist: ");
//              context.addMessage(new ErrorMessage("msg.file.notdownloaded"));
//              context.setForwardName("failure");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File exist: ");
                if (resourceDetail.getResourseImageType().equals("pdf")){
                    System.out.println("pdf: ");
                    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='myfile.pdf'");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("jpeg: ");
                    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='myfile.jpg'");
                }
//              response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
                System.out.println("stream: ");
                stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                response.setContentLength(stream.available());
                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();      
                os.close();
                response.flushBuffer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the `resourceDetail.getResourseImage()` got the image bytes stream? if that, write the bytes data to response output stream directly instead of get input stream from image file.

Comment: Hi gavincook, are you able to please provide me with the code for this please, I can not find it.

Comment: sure, i post an answer, take a look.

Comment: What is written to the System.out? If it is an URI, it is not a File/FileInputStream. You could use the more general Path and Files.exists or URL.openStream (InputStream).

Comment: Hi Joop, the system.out is as per under jpeg and pdf  below.

Answer (score 0):

`resourceDetail.getResourseImage()` got string data, you can directly write the data to response by using: `OuputStream#write(bytes)`. In you case, just use ·os.write(resourceDetail.getResourseImage().getByets());` to do this.

The Sample code:

```
resourceDetail = MySQLConnection.resourceDownload(fileID);
try {
    System.out.println(
            "resourceDetail.getResourseImage(): " + resourceDetail.getResourseImage());

        if (resourceDetail.getResourseImageType().equals("pdf")) {
            System.out.println("pdf: ");
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='myfile.pdf'");
        } else {
            System.out.println("jpeg: ");
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='myfile.jpg'");
        }
        response.setContentLength(resourceDetail.getResourseImage().length());
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        os.write(resourceDetail.getResourseImage().getBytes());
        os.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gavincook, I appreciate all your help. "os.write(resourceDetail.getResourseImage());"  gives the error "The method write(int) in the type OutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (String)".

Comment: Is `resourceDetail.getResourseImage()` got string data? Can you show me an example of image data got from `resourceDetail.getResourseImage()`.

Comment: jpeg is: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAgGBhAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAQFR

Comment: pdf is : data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvU

Comment: Now no errors; however, when I click on the download button the file does not download. The System.out commands display the data at each point. There are no errors on the console.

Comment: Oh, your code has an extra } before the catch that I removed.

Comment: Also, is the "FileInputStream stream = null;" and other "stream" references needed? They seem superfluous to me.

Comment: This outputs the file "OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\Desktop\\" + outputFile);"; however, the file can not be read (neither jpeg nor pdf).

Comment: Seems the image data is invalid. Can you first test your data on https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: Hi gavincook, thank you so much for all your help. I pasted the base64 into the page and the image was generated successfully.

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo project to reproduce on github? so i can take a deep view on it directly.

Comment: Hi gavincook, I am afraid that is above my abilities. I am not a programmer by trade and am doing this in my spare time for my Scouts.

Comment: I took this approach after first trying to do the download using jQuery. That worked for chrome; however, not IE. So I read up and decided to try to do this by using java.

Comment: I do not understand the solution provided so far (my lack of knowledge).

It seems that I have "response" and "os" which are trying to do the same thing. "response" returns the data to the client. My issues with this are:
"resourceDetail.getResourseImage()" is not being passed back
Will this not still give an issue with IE?
What do I do in the jQuery (under .done) to then write the data to the file?
"os" is writing direct to disk. Which is what I thought the answer was to get around the IE incompatibility? However the file can not be read (the same as the IE issue I had in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

While this solution does not directly answer the issue with java it does give me a solution. I started with using jQuery which worked with Chrome and not IE. I was told it was not possible to active downloading images with jQuery and that I needed to do it via java. However, I have now found:

http://danml.com/download.html

Kind regards,

Glyn